# InstallJammer project update or uninstall

Tags: installation, auto-update

I have a problem with my installJammer project. Currently am creating a setup for a java application. 
I need to create an action that is invoked when the user selects to upgrade to the new version. To be more clear, a window with two radio buttons (Update and Upgrade) appear if a previous version exists.

When the user clicks upgrade, the existing version is to be upgraded with the existing. How can I do this?

Expecting any one's help as I need the solution ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the <%UpgradeApplicationID%> you can update your exciting project with current. for the suitable effect,you should set an upgrade application pan in installjammer.after that,set the actions that is - check for previous install,get previous install info.then you should set a virtual text action for perfect upgradation.in virtual test action, check the advance properties,mark the auto update as "Yes",then fill the virtual text as <%UpgradeApplicationID%>. after that furnish the message box,exit etc.as your requirement wishes. hop you will get this. if any more confusions, please refer installjammer user guide by downloading the following link - www.installjammer.com/docs/InstallJammerUserGuide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will do this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Dear friend,

In installjammer, An upgrade installer is one that skips some of the procedures of
a regular installer and adds its information to the uninstall of the previously-installed
application. you can upgrade your project by using upgrade application ID can be accessed by using the **<%UpgradeApplicationID%>** virtual text.

Comment: Can you explain the context please as I am new to InstallJammer? What value I will get in the <%UpgradeApplicationID%>. And where should I use this?